# What is the difference between 殺{さつ}人{じん} and 殺{さつ}害{がい}?

Tags: word-choice, usage

What is the difference between 殺人 and 殺害? As I know, both of them mean "killing". I found the words in these sentences:

> 秋田運転手刺殺事件、男を逮捕 強盗**殺人**容疑で。
>  金品を奪い取る目的で**殺害**した疑い。

Comment: Off the top of my head... You'd say (~~を)殺害する but not (~~を)殺人する.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic meanings are:

殺人: killing a human.

殺害: killing.

殺害する: kill.

So, 殺害 includes 殺人. But, you cannot change every 殺人 to 殺害.

Japanese criminal law defines a crime called 強盗殺人罪 (A robbery homicide).
So, if you refer to this crime, 殺人 is used.
There are several similar crimes like 殺人罪 (A murder).

Answer (score 4):

Note the kanji 「人」 in 殺人. This implies that this word is only used when referring to the **act of killing a human**. 殺害 can include animals as well. Also note that 殺人 is only a noun (or no-adjective). 殺害 is also a noun, but can also be used as a -suru verb.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this is right. [大辞林](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E6%AE%BA%E5%AE%B3&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_satugai_-010) defines 殺害 as 人を殺すこと。  So do all the other monolingual dictionaries I checked. [類語例解辞典](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/9324/m0u/) says 「殺人」「殺害」は、人を殺すことだが、ふつうは「殺人」が使われる。

Answer (score 2):

Simply, 殺人 is a noun, "the act of killing another human: homicide", and 殺害 is a verb, "to murder / to mortally wound".

Comment: But 殺害 can be used as a noun, too, no? eg: [「ウサーマ・ビン・ラーディンの殺害が確認され・・・」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BB%E3%83%93%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E6%AE%BA%E5%AE%B3)